# I am searching for javascript or PHP to render LaTeX to an image. Like https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?<expression>

Tags: graphics, javascript, php

On my website (school/math) my users need 24 images for a game. The content of every image is a LaTeX expression, client-side rendered to an image with this code: *src = "https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?"*
But I am not happy with so many calls per game, sometimes 30 of my students are playing at the same time. I prefer rendering in PHP serverside, or javascript clientside. I don't have Node.js (think I cannot run this on my hosted server). I like to be 'self supporting' and not depending on codecogs.

Can anybody help me with a snippet, link or suggestion? Thnx!

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot just replace the images with [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) or [KaTeX](https://katex.org/)? (These would be the javascript solutions. For self-hosting, the full default MathJax installation is huge and can be a burden; depending on your needs you can trim a lot from the installation. For example, [for this person](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-04-02-deploying-mathjax) only 1.7mb is required; when I hosted MathJax on my own website before, my trimmed installation is 20mb.

Comment: For MathJax at least, you also have the option of [counting on a CDN to host the javascript files](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/start.html).

Comment: Hi Willie Wong thnx for this comment. I am using KonvaJS (based on HTML5 Canvas), and I don't know how to combine the by MathJax formatted HTML with Canvas/KonvaJS. Indeed, on my website I am using Mathjax on all HTML-pages.
Want have a look? https://www.wiskunjetrainen.nl//letteroefeningP.php for the MathJax and https://www.wiskunjetrainen.nl//letteroefeningL.php for the (Canvas) games

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my expertise. But if the issue is dynamically generated content, then you can manually invoke MathJax rendering after the content is written. [See the documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html) for more details. In principle you can also use MathJax to convert LaTeX-style input strings to alternative formats (MathML, SVG, etc) to combine with your other code; the documentation at the above link also tells you how to do that.